# How to say ”entangled parking space”?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests

As an official translator, I need to be loyal to the text in such a manner that no words are omitted. In translation of title deeds there’s a section which specifies the metes and bounds of the property in question. In this very part, the specifications of the parking space has been mentioned in to the bargain where there are TWO words meaning “ entangled parking”.

To be more specific, there are some old buildings with the capacity of 4 parking space. These four cars, particularly the ones which have been parked ahead, cannot leave the parking since there are two other cars parked behind them! Now how can I translate this?

---

> update: I have asked this question at law community as well.

https://law.stackexchange.com/q/44573/27535

Comment: Due to the legal nature of this question, you should probably speak to a legal person. There might be a technical term that we don't know. See [law.se].

Comment: Thanks but I just want to know what native speakers say in such a situation.

Comment: Natives very rarely speak about the legal implications of parking spaces. The cars would be 'blocked in', but that is pretty colloquial. You've got single word request and phrase request tags, which are you after? Please include the sentence in the original language and your translation.

Comment: It depends on the context. If you are describing this for a contract, I would look to construction or zoning terminology, since the reader of the contract is obligated to know the terminology (or fail to at their own peril). If you are translating a marketing brochure, I don't think there is a single common word. You could in that context replace with a footnote or explanation (e.g., use "blocked spot*" with "* Although two cars fit, parking in the rear spot blocks the person in the front spot in."

Comment: @jimm101 Thanks for your comments. I guess blocked spot or blocked parking would serve my purpose.

Comment: @marcellothearcane پاركينگ درگير in Persian meaning entangled or blocked spot/parking space.

Comment: (Midwestern American here) If my car was in a parking space with another car or cars blocking me from leaving the parking space, I would say my car was "parked in".

Comment: Crossposted on Law.SE, where I have posted an answer: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44573/how-to-say-entangled-parking-space

Comment: You can google for ***tandem parking***.

Comment: Just for completeness, 'entangled' is definitely the wrong word and would not be understood as meaning what is intended, even in context.

Comment: You could call it a “landlocked” space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-site duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44573/how-to-say-entangled-parking-space.

Answer (score 5):

The term is ***tandem parking***.

Quora:

> *Tandem parking* generally means that you are assigned two parking spots, configured like a single, double-length perpendicular parking spot. One space will be in front of the other, such that one car will have to pull out in order to access the second one.
> <sub>[Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-a-tandem-parking-and-whats-the-difference-between-tandem-parking-and-deeded-parking)</sub>

Law Insider:

> **Tandem parking** means that two or more automobiles are parked on a driveway or in any other location on a lot, lined up behind one another.
> <sub>[law insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/tandem-parking)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned [phrase-requests](/questions/tagged/phrase-requests), "***parked in***" should work in your context -

> ## Park (someone or something) in
>
> ---
>
> : To park one's car in front of someone or someone's vehicle, thus
> preventing them from leaving their own parking space.
>
> ---
>
> Example sentences -
>
> - *If you hadn't parked me in, I wouldn't have had to push your car out of the way with mine, so really the damage is your own fault!*
> - *Some idiot parked in a massive delivery truck on the small side street, so now no one can pass through.*

([thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/parking+in))

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I regret to say that I have been misunderstood. Your beautiful example focuses on a verb and I was looking for an adjective in a translation when one cannot make any additions and omissions.

Comment: @BehzadFalahati - It's an idiom.